# How do I count the number of rows in a SQL Server table which has a certain value for a key combination?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called `ExcludedPositions` as follows:

```
HoldingID [int] NOT NULL
CloseOfBusinessDate [date] NOT NULL
ReasonCode [tinyint] NOT NULL
```

I want to find which unique `HoldingID/CloseOfBusinessDate` combination has the most `ReasonCode` values of 6. I have made various attempts at this, but none were even close to a solution. Please advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would take the top record ordered descending by count of groups with a reason code of 6.

```
SELECT TOP(1) -- WITH TIES <- Will return multiple records when more than one group matches the criteria. 
    HoldingID,
    CloseOfBusinessDate 
FROM
    YourTable
WHERE
    ResonCode=6 
GROUP BY
    HoldingID,
    CloseOfBusinessDate 
ORDER BY
    COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: This is a great answer. The only caveat to this would be that if you have two sets of data with the same number of rows it will only return 1 of them.

Comment: TOP 1 WITH TIES might solve the caveat thingy

Comment: But then I have scroll through the results and count them up. I want the count displayed as part of the query results.

Comment: @Scott - You could add COUNT(*) As RecordCount as a field in the SELECT clause.

Comment: @Scott - Feel free to mark the question answered if it worked out.

Comment: Yes, of course Ross. Done.